# let f be a function such that $\int _{-2}^3\:f\left(x\right)dx\:=\:8$ what is the value of $\int _{-3}^2\:f\left(y\right)dy\:$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

let f be a function such that $\int _{-2}^3\:f\left(x\right)dx\:=\:8$ what is the value of $\int _{-3}^2\:f\left(y\right)dy\:$ ?

I know that y = f(x) so the integral I am looking for is $\int _{-3}^2f\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\:dx\:$ ?

I think the answer to this will just be -8 but I am not sure how to prove it

if not then please give me a direction of how to approach it

Comment: $y$ is a dummy variable. You may change it to $x$ if you want to.

Comment: No assumption on $f$ ? It will be difficult to answer the question then...

Comment: sadly no this is all the details we were given

Comment: Please check for any typos in the question.  As written, the value of the integral could be anything.

Comment: It looks like a didactic exercise in which information about the parity (even or odd) of the function is given. For example, if $f$ is even, then you can make the change of variable $x=-y$ to get $8=\int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx=\int_{2}^{-3}f(-y)(-1)dy=\int_{-3}^{2}f(y)dy$.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well , next to the particular question nothing specific was said but I will look more carefully if it was mentioned somewhere else there since it is only one of multiple. Thanks a lot